# Deadlock when callin async method synchronously

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Obviously I created a deadlock here in my `Execute` Method which basically wraps
an asynchronous implemtation.

```
 public IEnumerable<IDataPoint> Execute(Guid batchId, Guid parameterId, DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, int maxNumberOfDataPoints)
        {
            return this.ExecuteAsync(batchId, parameterId, startDateTime, endDateTime, maxNumberOfDataPoints)
                .ConfigureAwait(false)
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
        }


public async Task<IEnumerable<IDataPoint>> ExecuteAsync(Guid batchId, Guid parameterId, DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, int maxNumberOfDataPoints)
{
    var foundDataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();

    startDateTime = startDateTime.WithoutMilliseconds();
    var firstDataPoint = await this.GetFirstDataPointBeforeDateTimeAsync(batchId, parameterId, startDateTime).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var lastDataPoint = await this.GetFirstDataPointAfterDateTimeAsync(batchId, parameterId, endDateTime).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var numberOfDatapointsToSubstract = firstDataPoint == null ? 0 : 1;
    numberOfDatapointsToSubstract += lastDataPoint == null ? 0 : 1;
    var dataPoints = await this.GetDataPointsBetweenDateTimesAsync(batchId, parameterId, startDateTime, endDateTime, maxNumberOfDataPoints - numberOfDatapointsToSubstract).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (firstDataPoint != null)
    {
        foundDataPoints.Add(firstDataPoint);
    }

    foundDataPoints.AddRange(dataPoints);

    if (lastDataPoint != null)
    {
        foundDataPoints.Add(lastDataPoint);
    }

    return foundDataPoints.OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp);
}
```

While `ExecuteAsync` is working just fine `Execute` does not terminate.
I don't get the problem. It seems to be a deadlock but I don't see the cause.

Wrapping `ExecuteAsync` like this works, though:

```
return Task.Run(
                    async () =>
                        await this.ExecuteAsync(batchId, parameterId, startDateTime, endDateTime, maxNumberOfDataPoints)
                            .ConfigureAwait(false))
                .ConfigureAwait(false)
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
```

Main difference is of course that `ExecuteAsync` is being wrapped in a Task.

UPDATE:
I thought that `ExecuteAsync` will be always executed on a different thread than the callers and by explicitley disabling context sync I would be fine but obviously I am wrong.

Comment: "Deadlock when callin async method synchronously" - yes, this is an expected consequence, which is why you are **not meant to do that**. The cause is a possible sync-context deadlock. - it is very well understood and documented. Sync over async and async over sync are both anti-patterns; the first is especially worthy of avoiding, because of this exact scenario. If you ever find yourself calling `.Result` or `.Wait()` on something **without knowing that it is already complete**: you've made an error.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html
If you are going to block and use ConfigureAwait you need to use it all the way down. Still not best practice to block on async code though.

Comment: yes but I did use ConfigureAwait(false) all the way down. here is no ui thread and I'd expect the execute method to block until executeasync finished on a different thread.

Comment: This depends on how you are calling `Execute`, but you didn't show that code.

Comment: well I guess it would be too much to show the full call stack here. can you explain possible issues?

Comment: The issue is obvious. You block the call. Don't do that. `ConfigureAwait(false)` isn't a fix - it doesn't do anything here because there's no await operation to configure.

Comment: As for why `Task.Run` works, it executes `ExecuteAsync` on *another* thread, and awaits for it on that other thread. If `ExecuteAsync` blocks itself before the first *real* awaitd, you'll get a deadlock in the first version but not the second. What does `GetFirstDataPointBeforeDateTimeAsync` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question of "why does this deadlock", but it's something to think about and it was getting too long for comment.

If your goal is to provide synchronous and asynchronous methods just to give anyone using your code the option of using either, you have two options:

**Don't**

As you have found, wrapping asynchronous code like this is risky, and the risk should be:

1. Known by the caller. Those using the `Execute` method probably won't know that it wraps an asynchronous method and could cause problems. (especially if this is in a library and they don't have easy access to the source code)
2. Assumed by the caller. The recommendation is always to `await` an `async` method. If someone using your code really wants to wait on it synchronously, then that risk belongs with them. But if you provide a synchronous wrapper yourself, they'll blame you for any deadlocks.

So you could just delete your `Execute` method and people can deal with it.

**Do it differently**

If you really want to provide a synchronous version, you can follow the pattern set by Microsoft. They do sometimes provide synchronous and asynchronous methods to do the same thing, but their implementations are *completely* different. They don't just wrap the asynchronous method.

You can see this in their source code. For example, compare [`File.InternalReadAllText()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L290) (which is used by [`File.ReadAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.0)) with [`File.InternalReadAllTextAsync()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L699) (which is used by [`File.ReadAllTextAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltextasync?view=netcore-3.0)).

So, write a synchronous version that doesn't use *any* asynchronous methods.